# Bootstrap modal over another modal Scrolling problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

So I have created a modal in bootstrap in inside this first modal a place a button for opening a second modal. It works perfectly . But when i close the 2nd modal the first modal scroll doesn't work. Rather if i scroll then the main body scrolled. So How can i solve this.
[image: with 1 modal]

[image: with 2 modal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your jQuery Code

```
<script>
    $('#id_ofyou_secondary_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {

      $('body').addClass('modal-open');

    });
</script>
```